# converting Matlab Neural Network into C++ Neural Network

Tags: c++, matlab, neural-network

I created a Neural Network in Matlab with newff, for handwritten Digits recognition.

I just trained it to recognize only 0 & 1 values from images.

with 3 Layers, Input Layer has 9 Neurons, Hidden Layer has 5 Neurons, and output Layer 1 Neuron,and there is 9 inputs.

my out puts are 0.1 & 0.2 ,and all Layers outputs function are "tansig".

I test it in Matlab and Network works Fine. now I want to create this network in c++ , I Wrote the Code and I copied all the Weights and Biasses(total 146 weights).
but when I put the same input data to Network the output value is not correct.

can anyone guide me?

this is my networks code:

```
here's my networks code...

public class Neuron
{
    public Neuron()
    { }
    public Neuron(int SumOfInputs)
    {
        m_SumOfInputs = SumOfInputs;
    }
    public double act(double[] Input, double[] weight, double bias)
    {
        double tmp = bias;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_SumOfInputs; i++)
            tmp += (Input[i] * weight[i]);
        m_output = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.Exp(-tmp));
        return m_output;
    }
    public double m_output;
    private int m_SumOfInputs;
};

public class Net
{
    public Net()
    {
        int i;
        //net1 , net2
        //initializing inputLayer Neurons
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            InputLayer[i] = new Neuron(9);
        //initializing HiddenLayer Neurons
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            HiddenLayer[i] = new Neuron(9);
        //initializing OutputLayer
        OutputLayer = new Neuron(5);
    }
    public double Calculate(double[] inputs)
    {
        double[] ILay_Outputs = new double[9];
        double[] HLay_Outputs = new double[5];
        //inputLayer acting
        ILay_Outputs[0] = InputLayer[0].act(inputs, IW1, Ib[0]);
        ILay_Outputs[1] = InputLayer[1].act(inputs, IW2, Ib[1]);
        ILay_Outputs[2] = InputLayer[2].act(inputs, IW3, Ib[2]);
        ILay_Outputs[3] = InputLayer[3].act(inputs, IW4, Ib[3]);
        ILay_Outputs[4] = InputLayer[4].act(inputs, IW5, Ib[4]);
        ILay_Outputs[5] = InputLayer[5].act(inputs, IW6, Ib[5]);
        ILay_Outputs[6] = InputLayer[6].act(inputs, IW7, Ib[6]);
        ILay_Outputs[7] = InputLayer[7].act(inputs, IW8, Ib[7]);
        ILay_Outputs[8] = InputLayer[8].act(inputs, IW9, Ib[8]);
        //HiddenLayer acting
        HLay_Outputs[0] = HiddenLayer[0].act(ILay_Outputs, HW1, Hb[0]);
        HLay_Outputs[1] = HiddenLayer[1].act(ILay_Outputs, HW2, Hb[1]);
        HLay_Outputs[2] = HiddenLayer[2].act(ILay_Outputs, HW3, Hb[2]);
        HLay_Outputs[3] = HiddenLayer[3].act(ILay_Outputs, HW4, Hb[3]);
        HLay_Outputs[4] = HiddenLayer[4].act(ILay_Outputs, HW5, Hb[4]);
        //OutputLayer acting
        OutputLayer.act(HLay_Outputs, OW, Ob);

        return OutputLayer.m_output;
    }
    //variables
    Neuron[] InputLayer = new Neuron[9];
    Neuron[] HiddenLayer = new Neuron[5];
    Neuron OutputLayer;

    //net2 tansig tansig tansig
    double[] IW1 = { 0.726312035124743, 1.01034015912570, 0.507178716484559, -0.254689455765290, 0.475299816659036, 0.0336358919735363, -0.715890843015230, 0.466632424349648, 0.565406467159982 };
    double[] IW2 = { 0.866482591050076, -0.672473224929341, 0.915599891389326, 0.310163265280920, -0.373812653648686, -0.0859927887021936, 0.0100063635393257, 0.816638798257382, -0.540771172965867 };
    double[] IW3 = { 0.138868216294952, 1.93121321568871, -0.564704445249800, 0.834275586326333, 3.08348295981989, 0.899715248285303, -0.661916798988641, 6.00562393127300, 6.11939776912678 };
    double[] IW4 = { 0.578089791487308, 0.885170493965113, -0.992514702569606, 0.415980526304333, -0.706140252063166, 0.442017877881589, -0.449053823645690, -0.0894051386719344, -0.348622179369911 };
    double[] IW5 = { -0.407756482945129, 0.0786764402198765, 0.972408690276837, -0.959955597431701, -0.977769442966978, 1.52121267506016, 0.503296357838885, -3.31593633455649, -3.47834004737816 };
    double[] IW6 = { -1.17474983226852, 0.870140308892922, 1.50545637070446, 0.369712493398677, -0.569857993006262, -0.732502911495791, -0.668984976457441, -1.48023312055586, -0.893472571240467 };
    double[] IW7 = { -0.860518592120001, -1.48432158859269, 0.957060799463945, -0.680797771869510, -0.270752283410268, -0.218766920514208, 0.168091770241510, -2.50326075864844, -0.800988078966455 };
    double[] IW8 = { 0.436492138260917, 0.280081066366966, 0.484813099857825, -0.310693876078844, 1.60359045377467, 1.57343220231689, -1.21552190886612, 2.03276547165735, 1.27245062411707 };
    double[] IW9 = { 1.66853306274827, -1.59142022586958, 0.862315766588855, 0.676048095028997, -2.22623540036057, -1.48036066273542, -0.0386781503608105, -5.18214728910353, -5.21258509200432 };

    double[] HW1 = { 0.577543862468449, 0.452264642610010, -0.869014797322399, 0.122435296258077, 0.507631314535324, 0.0386430216115630, -0.398222802253669, -0.614601040619812, 1.43324133164016 };
    double[] HW2 = { 0.163344332215885, 0.434728230081814, -3.04877964757120, -0.118300732191499, -2.63220585865390, 0.443163977179405, -2.11883915836372, 2.07955461474729, -3.94441429060856 };
    double[] HW3 = { -0.156103043064606, -0.482049683802527, 1.24788068138172, -1.05731056687422, -0.615321348655331, 0.214815967784408, 0.375762477817552, -0.728649292060764, -0.212151944122515 };
    double[] HW4 = { 1.78276088127139, 1.15086535250306, 1.25967219208841, -0.446026243031773, -3.94742837475153, -1.33311929047378, -2.09356929069216, 0.0736879745054291, 1.51472991137144 };
    double[] HW5 = { 0.744372844550077, 0.400815326319268, -4.94686055701529, 0.444773365537176, 2.65351865321717, 1.87143709824455, 1.74346707204902, -3.28220218001754, 5.78321274609173 };

    double[] OW = { -1.09112204235009, -7.13508015318964, -1.02533926874837, 3.80439015418632, -4.16711367340349 };

    double[] Ib =  {-1.77988445077976,
                -1.37323967952292,
                -0.547465218997906,
                0.331535304175263,
                -0.0167810612906040,
                0.734128501831859,
                -0.543321122358485,
                -1.13525462762255,
                1.82870615182942};
    double[] Hb =  {1.68321697741393,
                -0.862080862212137,
                -0.536310792063381,
                -0.772019935790668,
                1.51470472867250};
    double Ob = -0.156343477742835;
};
```

Comment: Not a hope without the code. Did you write the code yourself? Can you try it with a simpler netwrok to try to spot the problem?

Comment: tnx for rapidly answer.
yes in c++ i write a very simple network. and i'm sure i make a mistake in that code.
i also test a 2 layer net, just input and output, but doesn't work too.

Comment: Is that all of it? There's no closing brace on the `Net` class - BTW you have *lots* of memory leaks - you must delete what you new.

Comment: sorry doctorlove I can't understand "There's no closing brace on the Net class", my English isn't well, can you please say it in simpler words?

Comment: Your code has `class Net {`. The last line says `double Ob = -0.156343477742835;` I would expect a class to end with `};`. Did you miss something out?

Comment: Thats C++? Is not Java or C#?

Comment: oh yes, sorry my bad!
it is in C#, but i have the exactly same code in c++ on microcontroller.
I actually wrote this program for microcontroller in c++, but it was easier to test the program on computer, so i copied this program into C# too.
i'm sorry

Comment: i forgot to copy the "};" from my source code.
thanks for say that.

Comment: Maybe there is no need to do this. If you want to use it in C++, just call it in C++!

Comment: i did it because it was easier to me to create a GUI and make an Inputbox to draw the number on computer, and debug it.
but on microcontroller it was a little harder to me.

Comment: Check this library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/c-c-neural-networks/\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention in your description that you want to use the Tansig activation function, but in your code you have the implementation for the Logsig activation function. Tansig approximation would be:

```
2/(1+Math.Exp(-2*tmp))-1
```

I am also not sure how you get the weights for the input layer, are these perhaps the weights for the hidden layer. Matlab does not generate weights for the input layers since the inputs are directly connected to the hidden layer. Where net.IW are the weights for the first (hidden) layer, the weights for the subsequent layers (including output) are given by net.LW.

Besides the above I don't see obvious bugs/errors in your code, maybe try a simpler network first and train it to do the old and wise XOR relationship.

Lastly I would like to mention if you are writing this code for a micro-controller it's easier to do it in C and without objects. Your code will be smaller and faster. A step by step example is given [here](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~jxb/NN/nn.html).

Comment: Thanks Rainman.
Yes I got the weights from IW, LW and b.
Thanks for your advice and example, I will keep it in mind and use it when writing my microcontroller program, know i'm going to read this example.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

in matlab, before inputs go to the network, they all go to a function named `applyminmax` in a .m file named `mapminmax.m`, and then this function outputs are the network inputs.

after the simulation on network is done, the outputs go to a function named `reverse` in the same .m file.
and this function outputs is the final output of the Neural Network.